# How to enter non ascii characters (such as í ) in SQL Developer 18.1

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, non-ascii-characters

I am using SQL Developer v18.1 and the database version is Oracle 12c.

```
sql> select  *  from nls_database_parameters where parameter like 'NLS%CHARACTERSET';

PARAMETER                      VALUE
------------------------------ -------------------------
NLS_NCHAR_CHARACTERSET         AL16UTF16
NLS_CHARACTERSET               AL32UTF8
```

I would like to enter some non-ascii characters, such as 'í', but have no clue how to do that, even after some searches here and Google. Actually I am even unable to enter this example character here directly. I just copies it somewhere else and pasted in this question.

Thank you for the helps in advance!

Sam

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

Here's a table which is supposed to contain some data.

```
SQL> create table test (col varchar2(20));

Table created.
```

Check ASCII code for the character you'd want to insert, by using the `ASCII` function:

```
SQL> select ascii('í') from dual;

ASCII('í')
----------
     52103
```

OK; now we know its code so - insert it, but this time using the `CHR` function:

```
SQL> insert into test (col) values (chr(52103));

1 row created.

SQL> select * From test;

COL
--------------------
í

SQL>
```

Comment: Or get a new keyboard, use charmap, or on a Mac/Android, hold down the I key until the diacritics show up